# scipy.optimize for vector function

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to minimize a function which has multiple inputs but also multible outputs. More specific, I call an Excel calculation and want to constrain particular inputs and outputs of the function. So far I just managed to minimize the scalar function meaning multible inputs but just one output. Can anyone please guide me if such a problem can be solved by Python/Scipy?  I´d like to choose x so that smpkt is minimized and A is smaller than a particular value.

For example some code snippets:

```
def f1(x,params):
    y=F(x)
```

The function `F(x)` is an external Excel sheet with multiple inputs and outputs, the output should be y=[smpkt,A]. Now i´d like to minimize `smpkt` and keep `A` smaller than my constraint by choosing `x`.

So far I managed to minimize `y=F(x)`  y=[smpkt] as scalar by the following call:

```
res = optimize.minimize(f1, x0, args=params, method='COBYLA',options={'ftol': 0.1, 'maxiter': 5})
```

Any idea?

Comment: This comment is more for anyone else who happens to read this question. I think what you are asking is about "constrained minimization" which is available for certain algorithms in scipy.optimization.minimization. Constraints can be linear or nonlinear functions with inequality type bounds. You can also bound the parameters themselves. Key note is that not all minimizers support both or even either.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: I'm not sure the following does what you want to do.  In particular, you say "I'd like to keep variable "A" smaller than a particular value.", which is not the same as "I want to choose `x` so that `A` is as small as possible.".  For what it's worth, here's an answer for one interpretation of your question.*

If you want to minimize one component of the output, as suggested by your comments about the function `f1` (and you can't just modify `f1` to return only A), you'll need to wrap the existing function in another function that calls `f1` and returns just `A` (assuming `A` is, in fact, a scalar).

E.g.

```
def objective_function(x, params):
    smpkt, A = f1(x, params)
    return A
```

You could accomplish the same effect more concisely with a `lambda` expression:

```
res = optimize.minimize(lambda x, params: f1(x, params)[1],
                        x0, args=params, method='COBYLA',
                        options={'ftol': 0.1, 'maxiter': 5})
```

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.optimize.newton` allows this for the objective function to be vectorized (i.e. produce an array the same shape as the input):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html#scipy.optimize.newton